# Trying to open a file c system calls

Tags: c

I'm trying to open a binary file using system calls, I cannot use functions (fopen etc)

```
if ((fd2 = open("RandomStruct.bin",O_RDWR|O_CREAT)) == -1) 
        err_sys("Failed to open binary\n");
```

Is this line of code incorrect? thanks!
btw I get ": Error 0" O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. If you specify the O_CREAT flag, then open() needs another argument, which is the permission bits for the new file. e.g.

```
 open("RandomStruct.bin",O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0755);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the file permissions as mentioned in the other answer, however, `open()` is not a system call it's just another function (or a wrapper), just like `fopen()`, in libc which in turn call the `open` system call. I think you should check [syscall()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscall.2.html) instead, assuming you're using Linux, which allows you to invoke a system call directly by passing it's number (in this case `SYS_open`) and arguments (if your assignment requires using system calls).

Comment: You're answer is perfectly valid, but incomplete in my opinion.
You can both correct his misunderstanding AND help him fix his code

Comment: @AdelQodmani yes but I didn't want to repeat that besides calling open correctly here is irrelevant if the homework/assignment requires using system calls not functions as OP mentioned.